# Online learning with random action set?

Tags: regression, bayesian, sampling, online-algorithms

Suppose I have an online bayesian linear regression problem for which I can updated the posterior distribution of parameters. Using this posterior, I want to make a point forecast by sampling from it. In a complex regression environment, i.e. with non stationarities, model miss specification etc., it may not always be best to pick the posterior mean to minimize to out of sample objective. Therefore we have this online learning problem that should balance between exploitation/exploration of *where* to sample from the posterior. The tricky thing here is that if the posterior itself is the action set, it changes at each time step. Im wondering if there are any online learning algorithims that are suited to this problem?

Comment: Could you give us more details? It sounds like a pretty standard Bayesian optimization scenario, so I'm wondering where's the catch?

Comment: Essentially I have a bayesian linear regression problem and at each time step I update the posterior. Im using collaborative analytics whereby features are owned by different agents, therfore the parameter in the regression maps to a payment they should receive based on their contribution to the prediction. Therefore, I want to sample from the posterior at each time step, not necesarrily to minimize out of sample loss, but maybe out of sample variance in the parameters for example. But unsure how to learn "where" to sample from at each time step. @Tim

Comment: e.g. i tried fixing the action set to be normalized level sets, and each time step i select which level set to sample from, but this seems quite limiting. @Tim

Comment: Check https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2599

Comment: Thanks @Tim will check this out

Comment: @Tim Hi Tim, would you be able to elaborate a bit on what you mean by this is a "pretty standard BO" problem?